# Need Help With A Rewrite Issue

Tags: url-rewriting

On the site im getting this

"mysitehere.com/pro/my-everyday/?auth=my%20author%20title"

I would love to have it like

"mysitehere.com/pro/my-everyday/my-author-title"

I have looked around and found nothing that helps though im not sure exactly how to format it to work with my need.

---UPDATE---

Found out the past developer used the wrong tag in the links. I have fixed the space issue and now i get

"mysitehere.com/pro/my-everyday/?auth=my-author-title"

Now to hide the ?auth=

Comment: What is generating that URL? I don't recognize that `?auth=` parameter as being WordPress created, but maybe I've missed it.

Comment: It doesn't look like a rewrite issue so much as a trying-to-use-spaces-in-an-URL issue, by the way.

Comment: I have no clue whats causing that auth part. Its a website im looking at for another guy. I would like to do away with it though. @s_ha_dum Im not sure what that comment was for. That is part of the issue bit not the issue, and that is of no help at all your comment. Please be constructive.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to rewrite rules for author titles, check out the monkeyman rewrite analyzer to figure out, following code should be in your functions.php

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'my_insert_rewrite_rules');
function my_insert_rewrite_rules($rules) {
   // Implement this function to add all the new rules to $rules array passed in
    $newrules = array();
    $authors=get_users();//http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users
    foreach($authors as $author)
    {
        $author_slug = $author->display_name;
        $newrules['/'.$author_slug] = 'auth='.$author_slug;
    }
    return $newrules+$rules;
}
```

Note: Above given code might not be exactly correct, I have written down steps to give you an idea of how it can be implemented, The rewrite analyzer plugin should help you figure out the rewrite rules(it pretty much tells you how your wordpress installation behaves for the various urls), play with it a bit to get a hang of it

Comment: This answer is missing all of the code that would actually make it work. Please edit this to include the part glossed over in the comment block.

Comment: I got the plugin and tbh i still cant figure out whats going on. I know nothing of rewrites and the plugin dont tell you what to do with what are where to put it.

Comment: Still not working. The issue i think im having is a drop down author filter. All the "?auth=" links have been coded into the pages but removing them makes the pages not work. I think.... perhaps the dropdown is using this? i have no clue. I have never seen anything like this on a wordpress site its just not needed. Thing is i cant figure out how to fix or undo it.

Comment: Why would someone need a "?" in the url? http://somehting.com/somehtingelse/?author works but taking out the ? like so http://somehting.com/somehtingelse/author does not.